# Rails form_with errors (remote: true)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-ujs

How can I display errors using Rails **form_with** (remote form with Ajax) helper?

I have this code:

```
def create
  @incoming_package = IncomingPackage.new(tracking: params[:tracking])
  if @incoming_package.save
    redirect_to admin_incoming_packages_path, notice: "created"
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "error" # not displayed
  end
end
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_with url: admin_incoming_packages_path do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :tracking, required: true, autofocus: true, autocomplete: :off %>
  <%= form.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

If there is no errors rails-ujs + Turbolinks works fine and new package is automatically added on page.
How can I display errors (or anything) if a package failed to save?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to get you started:

On your form's view page:

```
<% if @incoming_package.errors.any? 
  <ul>
    <% @incoming_package.errors.each do |error| %>
      <li><%=error.full_messages%></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Then on your `create` action do:

```
def create
  @incoming_package = IncomingPackage.new(tracking: params[:tracking])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @incoming_package.save
      flash[:success] = "The package was saved."
      format.html { redirect_to admin_incoming_packages_path, notice: "created" }
      format.json { render json: {success: true}
    else
      @errors = @incoming_package.errors.add(:base, "Some custom message here if you like")
      flash.now[:danger] = "error" # not displayed
      format.html { render 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @incoming_package.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

You must also make sure your `new` action has:

```
@incoming_package = IncomingPackage.new
```

Comment: it is a remote Ajax form, I know how to display errors for standard forms (non Ajax forms)

Comment: But you're using "local: true" which disables the ajax submission when using form_with.  It's comparable to setting "remote: false" on form_for with Rails4.  I'll update the controller to show how to render via ajax but you'll have to remove the 'local: true' setting.

Comment: Ajax requests data via json whereas normal requests are in html. This allows you to respond to either type of mime request specifically.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check any errors ruby give a very easy way to do it

`@incoming_packages.errors.full_messages` will show all errors related to your model. also you can interact with all these errors

```
`<%if @incoming_packages.errors.any?%>
  <% @incoming_packages.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <%= message %>
  <%end%>
<%end%>`
```

Comment: More about AJAX and ruby on rails you can find at (https://medium.com/@n.matheuscarvalho/how-ajax-works-with-ruby-on-rails-85aa6cf2fb81)