# How to display errors in form_with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I'm trying to display error in a form_with. Here my code:

## booking/new.html.erb

```
(...)
<%= form_with(model: [@space, @booking], local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag :check_in, "Check in" %>
  <%= f.date_field :check_in, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= label_tag :check_out, "Check out" %>
  <%= f.date_field :check_out, class: "form-control" %>

  <%= submit_tag "Reserve", class: "btn btn-primary %>
<% end %>
(...)
```

This is the controller:

## bookings_controller.rb

```
(...)

  def new
    @space = Space.find(params[:space_id])
    @booking = Booking.new
    @query1 = session[:query1]
    @query2 = session[:query2]
  end

  def create
    @space = Space.find(params[:space_id])
    booking  = Booking.create(booking_params)
    unless booking.valid?
    #show your errors
      redirect_to new_space_booking_path(@space)
    else

      session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        line_items: [{
          (...)
        }],
        success_url: success_booking_payments_url(booking),
        cancel_url: new_booking_payment_url(booking)
        )

      booking.update_attribute(:checkout_session_id, session.id)
      redirect_to new_booking_payment_path(booking)
    end
  end


  private

  def booking_params

    params.require(:booking).permit(:check_in, :check_out).merge(state: 'pending', amount: @space.price, user: current_user, space: @space)
  end
end
```

Everything is working well, but I'd like to display the errors (both fields and base) in the form. I tried some solutions like [Rails form_with errors (remote: true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51066373/rails-form-with-errors-remote-true) but they seem not working in my case.

Comment: How are you rendering the new view in the controller?

Comment: Where's your create method? That's the only one that will generate an error.

Comment: I'm trying:
`if booking redirect_to new_booking_payment_path(booking) else render "spaces/show" end` but it doesn't work

Comment: There will never be errors in a show method.

Comment: is there any workaround to render the form that I placed in the "spaces/show"?

Comment: I've moved the form in the bookings#new but still not able to render the form with errors in case the validations fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create!` throws an error, `create` does not.

Probably want something like this.

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @space = Space.find(params[:space_id])
    @booking = Booking.new
    @query1 = session[:query1]
    @query2 = session[:query2]
  end

  def create
    @space = Space.find(params[:space_id])
    @booking  = Booking.new(booking_params)

    if @booking.save
       session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
         payment_method_types: ['card'],
         line_items: [{
           name: @space.address,
           images: [@space.photo],
           amount: @space.price_cents * (1 + (@booking.check_out - @booking.check_in).to_i),
          currency: 'gbp',
          quantity: 1
        }],
        success_url: success_booking_payments_url(@booking),
        cancel_url: new_booking_payment_url(@booking)
      )
      @booking.update_attribute(:checkout_session_id, session.id)
      redirect_to new_booking_payment_path(@booking)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def booking_params

    params.require(:booking).permit(:check_in, :check_out).merge(state: 'pending', amount: @space.price, user: current_user, space: @space)
  end
end
```

Comment: Now it `redirect_to new_space_booking_path(@space)` if the validations fail but still not able to show the errors in the form_with. Ideally, I'd like to show fields and base errors in the form.

Comment: The errors are in the booking, not the space.  Can't show what's not there.

Comment: booking is nested in space `new_space_booking_path(@space)` correspond to booking#new

Comment: Does the booking you created get tied to the @space in booking parameters? Otherwise they are not related in the code you have shown.

Comment: I added the booking_params above. I have :space_id amongst them.